# Append exchange bodies with aggregation strategy in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

How can i append camel exchange bodies in Aggregation strategy.

```
   public class MyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange newExchange, Exchange originalExchange) {
      //I want to append body of newExchange to originalExchange.
      // Currently I'm copying properties with following and returning exchange
      ExchangeHelper.copyResults(originalExchange, newExchange);
    }}
```

Comment: Short answer, yes.

Comment: how can i implement that

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html There are several sections showing how to append the bodies.

Comment: ok.Thanks.got it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you write "append" I assume the bodies are of type java.lang.String. An easy way would be to use a POJO aggregator (have a look at http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html):

```
public class AppendingAggregator {
    public String append(String existing, String next) {
        return existing + next;
    }
}
```

In your route builder use

```
AggregationStrategies.bean(AppendingAggregator.class, "append")
```

where you'd normally specify the aggregator.